# control number of decimal places in R .txt input - gps coordinates

Tags: r, gps, decimal

I'm trying to run a Delaunay Triangulation with GPS coordinates. As no two individuals may have the same coordinates, I have used jitter to add some variation. My problem is, however, that when I import my .txt dataset I lose 4 decimal places (e.g. `-32.59551498` becomes `-32.59551` in R). This reduction in decimal places results in 2 individuals having the 'same' coordinates (e.g. `Ind1 = -32.59551498`; `Ind2 = -32.59550923`, so both are displayed as `-32.59551` in R) so I can't run the Delaunay Triangulation. 
Any suggestions or help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: How are you importing your data set?  And are you sure that precision is being lost rather than this being an issue with the formatting of the numbers when displayed?

Comment: You should post your code here in order to help us helping you...

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Biegeleisen pointed out, make sure it's a question about importing and no printing the numbers on the screen.

```
x <- c(-32.59551498,-32.59550923)
x # return

[1] -32.59551 -32.59551
```

But all decimals are still there:

```
print(x, digits = 10)

[1] -32.59551498 -32.59550923
```

You can control the number of digits to print when printing numeric values using:

```
options(digits = 10)
x

[1] -32.59551498 -32.59550923
```

Comment: Thanks for the info./ suggestions. I'm a newby at R, so any help is much appreciated! I use the following code for importing my dataset:  Rdata<-read.table("C://Users//Gend//Desktop//R_FILES//Ch2_paper_R_input.txt",header = T)   I then did as suggested  print(Rdata$XYxrandom, digits = 10)   and all the decimals are then there. However, when trying to run the Delaunay triangulation > cn<-chooseCN(xy,res="nb",ask=F,type=1) , I get this error: Error in chooseCN(xy, res = "nb", ask = F, type = 1) : 
  Duplicate locations detected and incompatible with graph type 1-4.